# What return type should I use for my function to print Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: c++, function, fibonacci, return-type

I'm trying to write a function that prints all Fibonacci numbers between the range of x and y. I almost have it but I have no idea what return type to use for the function `genFib(int min, int max){` I thought bool was right but when I tested the code, the line `cout << genFib(5, 20) << endl;`prints `5 8 13 0` adding the zero at the end. What return type should I use to avoid having a zero print at the end? This is all of my current code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool perfectSquare(int x){
    int s = sqrt(x);
    return (s*s == x);
}
bool isFibonacci(int n){
    return perfectSquare(5*n*n + 4) ||
           perfectSquare(5*n*n - 4);
}

bool genFib(int min, int max){
    int newMax = 0, newMin = 0;
    if(min > max){
        newMax = min;
        newMin = max;
    }else{
        newMax = max;
        newMin = min;
    }
    cout << "Fib numbers: ";
    for(int i = newMin; i <= newMax; i++)
        if(isFibonacci(i)) cout << i << " ";
    return false;
}

int main(){
    cout << genFib(5, 20) << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not `void`?

Comment: If you don't want to print the result of `genFib`, why are you passing it to `std::cout`?

Comment: What are your specifications for the `getFib` function? Who told you it *must* return something? Who told you that it must return `false`? Why does it have to return anything at all? Why must it always return `false`?

Comment: And perhaps you might need to take a step back and relearn how calling a function work, and how output through `std::cout` works.

Comment: As for the zero and where it comes from, it might be clearer if you do something like `bool result = genFib(5, 20); cout << endl << "result = " << result << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

The last 0 you are seeing is there because you are returning false from `genFib()`, and then printing it. Because you are printing everything inside your `genFib()` method, you don't need to print the result from the method, or return anything from it. If you try the following, you won't print the result of `genFib()`, which is your trailing 0.

```
int main(){
    int x = 372; // Simply a random number
    genFib(5, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Since you also don't care about the return value of `genFib()`, you should return `void` instead of `false`. That would prevent anything from being printed if you do print the result of the method.

Comment: Ok, thanks that worked. I kept getting an error when I did ```void genFib()``` but I see I was making a simple mistake. Currently too tired to think straight so I'm making more mistakes than usual.